# How to sum the elements of a list if the difference of elements in another list is less than a certain value

Tags: python, list, sum, difference

Given that two lists have the same size. I want to first compute the difference between consecutive elements in one list, then sum the corresponding elements in the second list if the difference meets a criteria.

For example:

```
List_1 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9]
List_2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want to sum the corresponding elements in `List_2` if the difference between consecutive elements in `List_1` is less than or equal to 0.1. If the difference is greater than 0.1, then do nothing. In this case, the difference in `List_1` is `[0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]` then my expected list of sum is `[ 3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: I would guess `[3, 2, 1]` == `[L2[0]+L2[1]+L2[4], L2[1}+L2[4], L2[4]]` with one of L1's `0.1` index as a starting point of the L2 sum... but that's super strange.

Comment: @finefoot Sorry for confusion. If the difference > 0.1, then I want to ignore it. The last 1 comes from List_2[5].

Comment: @finefoot I would sum the first 3 numbers 1+2+4, then sum 4th and 5th; 8+16, and leave the last one as 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code essentially uses [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings)  and Python's built-in function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to provide suitable iterables for the `for` loop. I tried to add some explanatory calls to `print` to show what's going on:

```
# Your list input
X = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9]
Y = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]

# Calculate sums
Z = [Y[0]]
for x_1, x_2, y in zip(X, X[1:], Y[1:]):
    print(f"Z currently looks like this: {Z}")
    print(f"Is {x_1} to {x_2} leq 0.1? {x_2 - x_1 <= 0.1}", end=" ")
    if x_2 - x_1 <= 0.1:
        print(f"=> Add {y} to last sum in Z")
        Z[-1] += y
    else:
        print(f"=> Use {y} to start a new sum in Z")
        Z += [y]

print("Final result:", Z)
```

Will print:

```
Z currently looks like this: [1]
Is 0.1 to 0.2 leq 0.1? True => Add 2 to last sum in Z
Z currently looks like this: [3]
Is 0.2 to 0.3 leq 0.1? True => Add 4 to last sum in Z
Z currently looks like this: [7]
Is 0.3 to 0.5 leq 0.1? False => Use 8 to start a new sum in Z
Z currently looks like this: [7, 8]
Is 0.5 to 0.6 leq 0.1? True => Add 16 to last sum in Z
Z currently looks like this: [7, 24]
Is 0.6 to 0.9 leq 0.1? False => Use 32 to start a new sum in Z
Final result: [7, 24, 32]
```

Of course, you can just remove all calls to `print` and the code will still work.